# ldap search trying to retrieve memberUid under some ou value

Tags: php, ldap

```
dn: cn=eee,ou=ddd,ou=ccc,ou=bbb,ou=aaa,dc=proj,dc=com
```

I have memberUid under `cn=eee`

I need to search `memberUid` who is under `ou=ddd`, having `memberUid=john` ( 'cn' value could be anything )

I am using php code using `$filter = "(&(ou=ddd)(&(cn=*)(memberUid=john)))";`

I am not getting any results of above filter, could you please tell what wrong in above?

Comment: It's hard to see what's wrong with only limited insight. If you could give a bit more detail it would be much easier to spot an issue.

Comment: @heiglandreas I need to search memberUid who is under ou=ddd, having memberUid=john ( 'cn' value could be anything )

Answer (score 0):

The LDAP filter applies to attributes of the target entries. The entry `cn=eee,...` doesn't have an attribute `ou`.

Yet, it's possible to do a filter on attributes that are part of the DN of the entry :
`$filter = "(&(ou:dn:=ddd)(memberuid=john)))"`

Note that I've removed `(cn=*)` because it doesn't add any value, most likely all entries having a `memberuid` attribute also have a `cn` attribute.